# DROP command denied to user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, permissions

Okay. Apparently someone removed the DROP privilege from **root** (they have every other privilege granted), *presumably to prevent accidental deletion of tables*. Problem is now no users have the privilege. Upon trying to reassign the privilege, mysql responds with

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I tried creating a new user with the same privilege; same error.

```
Error creating account root@[hostname]: Access denied for user 'root'@localhost (using password: YES)
```

I double checked my who I'm authenticated as: root@localhost.

```
mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### MYSQL Grants

```
SELECT COUNT(1) MySQLGrantsCount,VERSION() MySQLVersion
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';
```

returns

```
+------------------+--------------+
| MySQLGrantsCount | MySQLVersion |
+------------------+--------------+
|               43 | 5.6.34       |
+------------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## How then do I grant the privilege?

Comment: MySQL Server Community edition on an Azure VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, then the problem is simpler than I expected.

It's time to hack the `mysql.user` table.

```
CREATE TABLE mysql.user_new LIKE mysql.user;
INSERT INTO mysql.user_new SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
UPDATE mysql.user_new SET drop_priv='Y',grant_priv='Y'
WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
UPDATE mysql.user A INNER JOIN mysql.user_new B USING (user,host)
SET A.drop_priv = B.drop_priv;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then, run this to verify:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

The reason you could not just run the `GRANT` command to fix this is the fact that you cannot grant a privilege that you currently do not own. Similarly, you can't use `RENAME TABLE mysql.user TO mysql.user_old,mysql.user_new TO mysql.user;` because `RENAME` requires the `DROP` privilege.